# How do I implement Provided Id in Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I need to provide unique identity to each record of an Hibernate entity. I was able to provide a unique identity by using the `@EmbeddedId` annotation to few entities. But for one particular entity I have to use `@ProvidedId` annotation to provide unique id. Please somebody let me know how can this be done.

Just to be clear this is not hibernate problem but a **Hibernate Search** (search engine framework) problem. The `@ProvidedId` annotation is supposed to generate unique id for each record of the DB table and store them in the index files.

Comment: This is hibernate search question. It might be confusing with hibernate. But hibernate search is different APIthan hibernate itself. I made it clear in the second paragraph